# Split large excel file into multiple small sheets based on column value

Tags: excel, vba

Hi i am new to vba i need to split the large excel file into multiple small sheets based on first 5 values in a column for example, i have a code 1396A0001A,1396A0002A i need to split based on first 5 digits in separate sheets that is 1396A.i have a vba code but the problem is that the excel splits based on entire value into separate sheet please help me with the code .

example of excel sheet

[image: excel sheet]

```vb
Sub SplitSheetIntoMultipleSheetsBasedOnColumn()
    Dim objWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim nLastRow, nRow, nNextRow As Integer
    Dim strColumnValue As String
    Dim objDictionary As Object
    Dim varColumnValues As Variant
    Dim varColumnValue As Variant
    Dim objSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    
    Set objWorksheet = ActiveSheet
    nLastRow = objWorksheet.Range("A" & objWorksheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For nRow = 2 To nLastRow
        strColumnValue = objWorksheet.Range("A" & nRow).Value
        If objDictionary.Exists(strColumnValue) = False Then
           objDictionary.Add strColumnValue, 1
        End If
    Next
    
    varColumnValues = objDictionary.Keys
    
    For i = LBound(varColumnValues) To UBound(varColumnValues)
        varColumnValue = varColumnValues(i)
        Set objSheet = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
        objSheet.Name = varColumnValue
        objWorksheet.Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy objSheet.Rows(1)
        For nRow = 2 To nLastRow
            If CStr(objWorksheet.Range("A" & nRow).Value) = CStr(varColumnValue) Then
                objWorksheet.Rows(nRow).EntireRow.Copy
                nNextRow = objSheet.Range("A" & objSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                objSheet.Range("A" & nNextRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            End If
Next
        objSheet.Columns("A:H").AutoFit
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `strColumnValue = Left(objWorksheet.Range("A" & nRow).Value, 5)` would give you the first 5 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Only some changes

```
Sub SplitSheetIntoMultipleSheetsBasedOnColumn()
Dim objWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim nLastRow As Integer, nRow As Integer, nNextRow As Integer 'each item must be defined
Dim strColumnValue As String
Dim objDictionary As Object
Dim varColumnValues As Variant
Dim varColumnValue As Variant
Dim objSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Set objWorksheet = ActiveSheet
nLastRow = objWorksheet.Range("A" & objWorksheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For nRow = 2 To nLastRow
    strColumnValue = Left(objWorksheet.Range("A" & nRow).Value, 5)   'edited
    If objDictionary.Exists(strColumnValue) = False Then
       objDictionary.Add strColumnValue, 1
    End If
Next

varColumnValues = objDictionary.Keys

For i = LBound(varColumnValues) To UBound(varColumnValues)
    varColumnValue = varColumnValues(i)
    Set objSheet = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
    objSheet.Name = varColumnValue
    objWorksheet.Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy objSheet.Rows(1)
    For nRow = 2 To nLastRow
        If Left(CStr(objWorksheet.Range("A" & nRow).Value), 5) = CStr(varColumnValue) Then   'edited
            objWorksheet.Rows(nRow).EntireRow.Copy
            nNextRow = objSheet.Range("A" & objSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            objSheet.Range("A" & nNextRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        End If
    Next
    objSheet.Columns("A:H").AutoFit
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank u. This is working and I need to set a path to save all the sheets as a files in same folder can u guide me with the code

Comment: Yes, but according to SO policy it is desirable to post it in another question, or edit the original one in that way which give the appropriate result. It is more nicely describe in SO Help sites. The reason of it to help future users to find an answer for their problem. Example: `Split and` **Save** `large ...`, and reveal your previous attempts to solve it.